# git updated a file and add it ,but fail

Tags: git, github

[image]
Please look at the screenshot.First,I updated a file and wanted to add it to the stage,but failed.It said the path was not right .Before adding it ,I had checked the path which was right.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't say the path isn't right, it says it can't create a lock. If no other git instance is running, you could try deleting the lock manually.

Comment: I wanted to add it to ../learngit/ .What's the matter wih the path  '../learngit/git..'  ?

Comment: @Xiaolong `'../learngit/git..'` files/folders cannot have a `..` suffix, but that is not the problem in your case, read the error message git throws

Comment: @Xiaolong: Git creates a lock file when touching the repository. Normally, the lock file would be removed on a successful end of the operation, but in this case, something went wrong, so the lock file is still there. Just `rm .git/index.lock`.